# Half html code output from php with hex code bug

Tags: php

I don't know exactly how to explain this but when I POST on my page or when I change a SESSION variable, sometime, not always, I will get half the html in plain text starting with a hexa code. I don't know what to do. Its always random, the hexa code is almost always different.

Exemple :

```
bc86
    <div>something...</body></html>
```

Comment: What's your file `.php` encoding? You could post here your code? We need more information.

Comment: php file encoding is utf-8. For the code, the only thing I have is a print screen of the browser of my client. My php file output html content, nothing special, just a lot of <table>.

Comment: This is utf-8 or utf-8 with bom? There is a difference.

Comment: UTF-8 only, without bom

Comment: Last thing that comes to my mind is invisible chars before `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

If there was a problem of encoding which is mostly possible then you can try the following before producing some HTML/text to client:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: The change is done, I'm waiting for my client to test it out. Something weird is that I've never encounter the error myself. Always my client or he's coworker (from another city). He send me print screen of the error and I've checked is browser from a Team Viewer.